# How to handle mouse scroll and key press events on Cytoscape.js canvas with tpology diagram

Tags: javascript, angular, events, cytoscape.js

I have some problems with handling events like scrolling using the mouse wheel or key press. I' ve tried something like this but it won't work:

```
this.cy.on('wheel', event => {
        //somecodehere
    });
```

I didn't find wanted events on Cytoscape.js documentation page: http://js.cytoscape.org/#events. But I thought a thing like this should work fine - unfortunately I was wrong. I try to figure out how to handle this event on my canvas.

What do I want to do with this? I want to make tooltip disappear when the user wants to scroll the page. I've already disabled zoom on scrolling - I want to enable zooming only while "CTRL" key is pressed and in this case, I also didn't find wanted event to handle this. Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DOM API.

```
document.getElementById("cy").addEventListener("wheel", function(){
   console.log("Wheeeellll");
});
```